# Stuck with obsolete kernel

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

My desktop was on the kernel 4.15.0-48-generic. Then in the middle of this May the system suggested to upgrade itself to the kernel 4.15.0-50-generic, and I said "OK".

The upgrade was unsuccessful, the desktop didn't boot after that. So I had to manually switch to the old 4.15.0-48-generic kernel, and purge the 4.15.0-50-generic kernel.

After that the system stopped to suggest upgrading its kernel, and I think there is a **setting** somewhere, which forces the system to stay on the old kernel.

How to roll the system back to its normal way of upgrading kernel?

Comment: I personally would suggest using the same method you marked the kernel to stay so you're not leaving issues for yourself when you next try and release-upgrade.  I use commands myself, so I'd look in my `history`  (I also have date/times in my log files to aid finding things, but it's not the default for command history).  I'd look for `apt-mark` (hold)

Comment: @guiverc - `apt-mark showhold` returns nothing...

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete output of the command: `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-generic
`

Comment: @user535733 - it returns nothing, I have only  `linux-image-<version>-generic` packages

Comment: Then install that metapackage: `sudo apt install linux-image-generic`, That metapackage is how Ubuntu pushes kernel upgrades.

Comment: @user535733 - thanks, it worked, I've got the new kernel. If you want, please reformulate your comments as an answer, and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install (or re-install) the metapackage `linux-image-generic`. That metapackage is how Ubuntu pushes kernel upgrades.

Check to see if it's installed: `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-generic`

If the result begins with 'ii', then the metapackage is already installed, and your problem is something else.

Any other result means that it's not installed. Install using apt: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic`